# How to update a value based on previous row's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table like below (sql server 2019):

```
Name  Total  Payment   BalanceForward     Date
A     NULL   NULL      0                  NULL
A     20     40        NULL               01-2021
A     100    50        NULL               02-2021
A     50     80        NULL               03-2021
B     NULL   NULL      30                 NULL
B     50     50        NULL               01-2021
B     50     80        NULL               02-2021
B     50     40        NULL               03-2021
C     NULL   NULL      100                NULL
........
```

What I want is to update "BalanceForward" column as it'll have `Balance Forward of previous row + (current row's Total - current row's Payment)`

Expected output:

```
Name  Total  Payment   BalanceForward   Date
A     NULL   NULL      0                NULL
A     20     40        -20              01-2021
A     100    50        30               02-2021
A     50     80        0                03-2021
B     NULL   NULL      30               NULL
B     50     50        30               01-2021
B     50     80        0                02-2021
B     50     40        10               03-2021
C     NULL   NULL      100              NULL
.......
```

What is the best way to provide it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you want to implement a running total. You can do this by using `sum over()` window functions and an `updatable CTE` as follows:

```
with bf as (
    select *,
        Sum(total-payment) over(partition by name order by date)
        + sum(balanceforward) over(partition by name order by date) newbf
    from t
)
update bf set balanceforward=newbf
where balanceforward is null
```

Example [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10cb1691b34b8e42efb0851affd6930d)

Comment: not working.. can u add a fiddle maybe?

Comment: @JesusHamdi Sure see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10cb1691b34b8e42efb0851affd6930d)

Comment: @JesusHamdi What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is a more robust version of Stu's answer. You can run it twice, any number of times with the same output.

```
with bf as (
    select *, sum(total-payment) over(partition by name order by date) + first_value(balanceforward) over(partition by name order by date) newbf
    from t
)
update bf set balanceforward=newbf
where date is not null;
```